# Include method can not load eagerly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have two classes that have one to many relationship.

names: `Access` and `Permission`

**Access.cs**

```
public class Access
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Permission> PermissionList { get; set; }
}
```

**Permission.cs**

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have built a one to many relationship in my context class

**MyContext.cs**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>(); // turn off code-first db initialization

    modelBuilder.Entity<Access>().HasMany<Permission>(o => o.PermissionList).WithOptional();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Access>().HasMany(o => o.PermissionList).WithMany();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I want to list all `Access`es with their `Permission`s but When I tried to get `Access`es from Entity Framework, `Permission`s can not be loaded eagerly. However I am using Include method in my repository.

**MyRepository.cs**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "", bool tracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;


        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);

        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            if (!tracking)
            {
                return orderBy(query).AsNoTracking<TEntity>().ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!tracking)
            {
                return query.AsNoTracking<TEntity>().ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't understand Why `PermissionList` cannot be loaded eagerly into `Access`

Comment: Check this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I have already checked that and I did the same but list PermissionList is still emty. Count is 0

Comment: Please show a complete example. It should work like you explained, so there must be something wrong with the rest of your code.

Comment: You map the association between both entities twice: WithOptional and WithMany. I suspect that causes the misbehaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public virtual List<Permission> PermissionList { get; set; }

var query= context.Entity.Include(d => d.PermissionList);
```

You can check the explanation [here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/06/what-is-eager-loading-and-what-is-lazy.html)

Comment: `virtual` is for lazy loading and not required for eager loading.

Comment: You are right @CodeCaster, but the Include method tells the EF to use an eager loading strategy, right?
At least(for me), when i check in Sql Server Profile, the returned query is using a Left Outer Join

Comment: Thanks for answer but my Include method takes parameter type of string. Additionaly query is a list of TEntity query=context.Set<TEntity>(); I use generic repository